# How to prevent ugly spikes in canvas font rendering?

Tags: javascript, canvas, stroke

When I draw text in canvas, I get ugly spikes, like this:

[image]

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/48m4B/

While for example in photoshop, I get this:

[image]

The code is just a classic strokeText:

```
ctx.font = '20px Arial';
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
ctx.strokeText('How to prevent ugly spikes?');
```

If it isn't possible to fix this, is there any workaround?

Comment: +1 for the awesome spiky effect...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set line join to:

```
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
```

you can also adjust the miter limit:

```
ctx.miterLimit = 2;
```

**[Modified working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/48m4B/2/)**

Comment: Great Answer @Ken Fyrstenberg +1 - here it is in a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/48m4B/1/ - :)

Comment: Thanks @jonathan your comment came at the same time I updated my answer with a fiddle as well. :)