# Thorn of text outline in canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using html5 canvas to draw some texts, but I got some ugly results, here is my sample code to draw the text:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = 80;
  var y = 110;

  context.fillStyle = "white"
  context.font = '13px Arial';
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  // stroke color
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.strokeText('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!', x, y);
  context.fillText('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!', x, y);
```

And I got this result

[image]

then I change the text to "abs" and got this

[image]

You can see the "M" and "s" looks ugly, does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Its due to font size , try to increase the fontsize

Comment: See this previous Stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988099/how-to-prevent-ugly-spikes-in-canvas-font-rendering/19988202#19988202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not due to the typeface nor size, but due to how the lines in the stroke path are connected.

By changing the line-join method the spikes will go away:

```
context.lineJoin = 'round';
```

Comment: Great. this helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you prefer sharp corners (without the miter-spikes,) try this:

```
context.lineJoin = 'miter';
context.miterLimit = 2;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hwG42/3/

It does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You might get better results when you use a different font.

Alternatively, you could use only fillText and create the outline with a [shadow](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#shadows).